# Java building chain of events which depends on each other

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I hava a set of methods of type `boolean` which are settings things up. Each method return `true` if busines logic was successfully executed and `false` if anything went wrong. I would like to break chain at first `fail`.

Are there any good practicies?

ATM I am doing something like this:

```
if (taskIsDone(task) && taskGenerateReport(task) && taskReportIsDone(task) && taskProcessReport(task)){
    log.info("Processing of task {} is done", task.getName());
} else {
    log.error("Task {} finished with error", task.getName());
}
```

Something like this works in my dev env but if scenario when for any reason order of methods would change logic like this is useless.

Could anyone give me a hint how to make it right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The evaluation of the condition is already short-circuiting. Does it work or not? You just want a way to make it "look nicer" or something?

Comment: making it "look nicer" is a side effect I would like to make sure if there is any possibility that for some reason `taskGenerateReport` condition would be evalueted before `taskIsDone`. In my dev it does work properly but I would like to be prepared for suprises when volume of operation will increase significantly

Comment: There is no reason `taskGenerateReport` would be evaluated before `taskIsDone` in Java with this code - unless you change the order yourself.

Comment: A good practice would be to use a state machine, and not so many booleans.

Answer (score 0):

As the other people said, the order of execution is from the left to the right.

In your case, I would call `task.isDone()` or `task.generateReport()` and so on, as it's related to the task which is in your case probably a domain object.